# How to get the ID of the input element from the jQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with checkbox and I get the jQuery object after submitting the form having the checked input elements.

```
var $form = $(e.currentTarget);
var $inputs = $form.find("input.form-check-input:checked")
```

The inputs looks like this:

```
inputs = {
  "0": {<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="/api/memory/23/" checked="checked">...},
  "1": {},
  "2": {},
  "3": {},
  "length": 4,
  "prevObject": {
    "0": {
      "0": {},
      "1": {},
      "2": {},
      "3": {},
      "4": {},
      "5": {},
      "6": {},
      "7": {},
      "8": {},
      "9": {},
      "10": {},
      "11": {}
    },
    "length": 1
  }
}
```

I have to extract the ID of input element in the `inputs` variable. I tried doing the following approaches but I get only the ID of element key like `0`, `1`. What I am missing here?

```
for (const entry in $inputs) {
    console.log(entry.id) // Outputs 0, 1, 2, 3, 4..
}

$inputs.forEach((entry) => {
    console.log(entry.id) // Outputs: TypeError: inputs.forEach is not a function
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to iterate the object of objects with help of `Object.entries`

This worked for me:

```
Object.entries($input).forEach(([key, val]) => {
   console.log(key, val.id)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery equivalent of `forEach` is called [`each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/).

```
$inputs.each((index, entry) => {
  console.log(entry.id);
});
```

Alternatively you can loop through the elements with [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).

```
for (const entry of $inputs) {
  console.log(entry.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`for ... in` loops work slightly differently. They loop through the object's *keys*, not its *values*.
Try this:

```
for (const entry in $inputs) {
    console.log($inputs[entry].id) // Should output the id
}
```

Comment: This worked as well. Thanks. What do you think here is the better approach `for .. in` or `Object.entries`?

Answer (score 0):

Does `$(e.currentTarget).find("input.form-check-input:checked").attr('id')` not work?

It's been my experience that if a Selector returns a single Item 99% of the time it's acts like you selected it by ID